# Send datetime to Rails to compare with where("updated_at > ?"

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building the Rails backend api for iOS app data sync.

I want to fetch the latest updated data when users tap the refresh button in iOS app.  To do that, I saved the Rails updated_at in iOS side, then send it when I call get call with updated_at params.

However, I don't know why this code doesn't work in Rails side.

@Rails EntriesControllers

```
# GET /entries
  def index
    entries     = current_user.entries
    updated_at  = params[:updated_at]

    # Filter with updated_at for reloading from mobile app
    if updated_at.present?

      entries = entries.where("updated_at > ?", updated_at)

    # Get all non deleted objects when logging in from mobile app
    else
      entries = entries.where(deleted: false)
    end

    render json: entries
  end
```

@Sending Rails Datatime format didn't work..

```
https://server.com/api/v1/entries?updated_at=2016-05-02T01:12:57.204Z
```

Even if I change the date of 2016-05-02T01:12:57.204Z to yesterday after I update some entries 1 minute ago, I only get empty data.

It works fine without params like this.

```
https://server.com/api/v1/entries
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For clean, tidy parameters you might want to use the `Time.now.to_i` epoch format. Then: `where('updated_at>?', Time.at(params[:updated_at]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest converting the incoming value for `updated_at` from a `string` to a `DateTime`.  Assuming that you're using the standard Rails timestamping, this will allow the database to do date-to-date comparisons for both accuracy and performance.

Here's the updated date comparison code:

```
entries = entries.where("updated_at > ?", DateTime.parse(updated_at))
```

Assuming that the incoming datetime format remains stable, this should work as you'd expect.  If you think that the datetime format might change, or you'd like to be more flexible in what you accept, consider changing the `DateTime.parse` to a call to a more robust date parser, such as [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

One last point: did you intend to filter for `deleted` in the date query, like is happening in the fallback query.  If you've implemented some soft-delete functionality, that might be useful to prevent end-user confusion.

Comment: Thanks!  It works as I expect!  >>delete Yes, I set deleted for soft-delete, what does it mean by "That might be useful to precent end-user confusion"?  what does that mean?

Comment: So glad to hear!  What I meant by the last statement is that end users (your iOS users) may be confused if list entries without a date filter and see only records that haven't been deleted, but if they specify a date for filtering, deleted records could suddenly show.  I meant that adding the filter for soft-delete to the date filter logic would keep those deleted records from being returned when they should not be.

Comment: I see.  I use data fetch without updated_at params only when users login, so it sends active data only.  When users tap the refresh, it gets data with updated_at, so iOS app can fetch deleted info to update it properly.  Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I mentioned the soft-delete filter for the updated_at query only in case it was unintentionally omitted.  Since you meant for it to work that way, it's good.

Comment: Ok, I understand why you said that now, thanks for mentioning that anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If you're changing the time to tomorrow, then you better have a time machine to put entries in the future. Try setting the time to yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a typo in your question, but you appear to have two question marks in your query parameter: `??updated_at=2016-05-02T01:12:57.204Z`. As a sanity check, verify `params` contains the key you want.